# Getting the name of the snapshot from a specific VM?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

How can I get the name of the snapshot that the particular machine is using?

I have tried:

```
Get-VM -Name vdix-test-01 | Get-Snapshot
```

but it returns blank..

Comment: Questions about VM management would be better on-topic at ServerFault. SO is for programming issues.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the correct cmdlets, maybe the VM doesn't have any snapshots?

If you want to see all the VMs that do have a snapshot, you can use this one-liner

Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | ft VM, Name -AutoSize

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also check the ExtensionData.Summary.Runtime.ConsolidationNeeded  in that case if you don't see the get-snapshot result but you see the yellow warning on a VM. + in case something really really went terribly wrong, then i think you can only do : https://grzegorzkulikowski.info/2012/07/17/watch-out-for-snapshots/  so yo you would be checking basically the vmdk names .